# std::max giving error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

Tags: visual-c++, stl, c++17

I am fairly new to C++. I was practicing some ds,algo.This code looks fine to me, but I am getting some error about function not taking 2 arguments. Though I get some error asked in stackoverflow none of the cases match my problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


int ropecutting(int n, int *cuts){
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    if (n < 0)
        return -1;
    
    int res = std::max(ropecutting(n-cuts[0], cuts), ropecutting(n-cuts[1], cuts),   ropecutting(n-cuts[2], cuts));
    if(res == -1) return -1;
    return res+1;
}
int main(){
    int n, cuts[3];
    std::cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
        std::cin >> cuts[i];

    std::cout << ropecutting(n, cuts);
}
```

The error I get is,

```
main.cpp
G:\software_installation\Visual Studio Community 2017\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xlocale(319): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
G:\software_installation\Visual Studio Community 2017\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\algorithm(5368): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
G:\software_installation\Visual Studio Community 2017\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\algorithm(5367): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'const _Ty &std::max<int,int>(const _Ty &,const _Ty &,_Pr) noexcept(<expr>)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=int,
            _Pr=int
        ]
G:\software_installation\Visual Studio Community 2017\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\algorithm(5368): error C2056: illegal expression
```

Wishing someone would point me out in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of [the overloads of `std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max), the only one which can be called with three arguments is

> ```
> template < class T, class Compare >
> constexpr const T& max( const T& a, const T& b, Compare comp );
> ```

So since it receives three `int` values, that function is attempting to use the third value as a functor to compare the other two, which of course doesn't work.

Probably the simplest way to get the maximum of three numbers is using the overload taking a `std::initializer_list<T>`. And a `std::initializer_list` can be automatically created from a braced list:

```
int res = std::max({ropecutting(n-cuts[0], cuts),
                    ropecutting(n-cuts[1], cuts),
                    ropecutting(n-cuts[2], cuts)});
```